# Disabling Comment Notifications for Post Author

Tags: plugins, comments, notifications

I am trying to disable comment notifications for post authors (or anyone else besides the site's admin) for a client's site. I've attempted to create a plugin that uses the pluggable function `wp_notify_postauthor`, but it does not seem to have an effect.

Here's the plugin code:

```
<?php
/**
 *
 *
 * @package   Disable_plugin_notifications
 * @author    Me
 * @link      <hidden>

 *
 * @wordpress-plugin
 * Plugin Name:       Disable Comment Notifications
 * Plugin URI:        <hidden>
 * Description:       <hidden>
 * Version:           1.0.0
 * Author:            <hidden>
 * Author URI:        <hidden>
 */


// Disabling comment notifications for post authors
if ( !function_exists( 'wp_notify_postauthor' ) ) {
    function wp_notify_postauthor() {
        return;
    }
}
```

I've also tried it without the 'return' in the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I skimmed through the source of the `wp_notify_postauthor()` function and noticed the [`comment_notification_recipients`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1261) filter.

I wonder if you could simplify your plugin to the following code snippet:

```
<?php
 /** 
  * Plugin Name: Disable comment/trackback/pingback notifications emails 
  * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/150141/26350
  */

add_filter( 'comment_notification_recipients', '__return_empty_array', PHP_INT_MAX );
add_filter( 'comment_moderation_recipients',   '__return_empty_array', PHP_INT_MAX );
```

where we use an empty  `$emails` array to prevent any notification emails from being sent.

The first filter is to stop `wp_notify_postauthor()` and the second to stop `wp_notify_moderator()`.

If you want only the *admin* user to receive email notifications, you can use this version:

```
<?php
 /** 
  * Plugin Name: Disable comment/trackback/pingback notifications emails except for admins.
  * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/150141/26350
  */

add_filter( 'comment_notification_recipients', '__return_empty_array', PHP_INT_MAX );
add_filter( 'comment_moderation_recipients', 
    function( $emails )
    {
        // only send notification to the admin:
        return array( get_option( 'admin_email' ) );
    }
, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

We could also override these two pluggable functions, but I don't use that here.

Comment: Tried this, but still got the notification email.

Comment: ok, I can't check it out now, will try it out later. But you can also try to set the `comments_notify` option to `0`.

Comment: I updated the answer, I did a silly mistake in the first version ;-) I've tested it and it seems to stop the comment notification emails on my install. Did you try this on a vanilla install? This method will of course not work if someone overrides the function and removes this filter.

Comment: Hmm, still happening for me, I'll try it out on a vanilla install tonight and see if it works there.

Comment: Just tried again on a vanilla install, this plugin being the only one installed / activated on the site. I have an admin account whose email is set as the site admin's. I then have a dummy account (diff email), the role of which is Author. I made the dummy the author of the default Hello World post, then went in (logged out) and commented on that post. I received two emails - one at the site admin's address (which is supposed to happen), and another at the dummy author's address (which is not supposed to happen).

Comment: I updated the answer with another filter. I did setup a new vanilla install and went through the same steps as you did. The second filter, `comment_moderation_recipients`, is the one that fires out the notification emails on the vanilla install.

Comment: That change did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @birgire's nice answer, here are some other variations:

1) Eliminate specific emails from the sending list

```
<?php
 /**
  * Plugin Name: Disable comment/trackback/pingback notifications for specific users.
  */
function squarecandy_eliminate_admin_comment_emails( $emails ) {
    // do not send to these specific emails
    $donotsend = array(
        'userone@example.com',
        'usertwo@example.com',
    );
    foreach ( $emails as $key => $email ) {
        if ( in_array( $email, $donotsend ) ) {
            unset( $emails[$key] );
        }
    }
    return $emails;
}
add_filter( 'comment_notification_recipients', 'squarecandy_eliminate_admin_comment_emails', PHP_INT_MAX );
add_filter( 'comment_moderation_recipients', 'squarecandy_eliminate_admin_comment_emails', PHP_INT_MAX );
```

2) Stop sending comment notifications to all users within certain roles

```
<?php
 /**
  * Plugin Name: Disable comment/trackback/pingback notifications emails except for certain roles.
  */
function squarecandy_eliminate_admin_comment_emails( $emails ) {
    // get all the users of the roles you want to restrict
    $users = get_users( 
        array(
            'role__in' => array(
                // this is the list of roles to repress comment notifications for
                'editor',
                'author',
            ),
            'fields' => array(
                'user_email',
            ),
        ),
    );
    // make an array of the emails not to send to
    $donotsend = array();
    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        $donotsend[] = $user->user_email;
    }

    foreach ( $emails as $key => $email ) {
        if ( in_array( $email, $donotsend ) ) {
            unset( $emails[$key] );
        }
    }
    return $emails;
}
add_filter( 'comment_notification_recipients', 'squarecandy_eliminate_admin_comment_emails', PHP_INT_MAX );
add_filter( 'comment_moderation_recipients', 'squarecandy_eliminate_admin_comment_emails', PHP_INT_MAX );
```

Comment: Testing this out now, I am fairly sure the values for role__in should be lowercase

Comment: @cogdog - cool - please do go ahead and test it. If you find that it does need to be lowercase in your testing, you could edit the post above and get credit for the edit.

Comment: It won't let me do an edit less than 6 characters! The function is working for me, i only used the filter for `comment_moderation_recipients` as my need is a student site where teachers (editor role) are moderating all comments. Students (author) role should see only notifications.

Comment: @cogdog - ok I changed it. Yeah, that 6 character edit thing is annoying - I've run into that before.